# DEM from Sentinel 1 C-band SAR

Tags: dem, sar, sentinel, insar

I have been using the standard protocol (ESA/ASF) to generate DEMs (actually DSM which is what S1 C-band gives) from Sentinel-1 C-Band SAR tiles. My locations are in the Eastern Himalayan foothills (Sikkim, India). Unfortunately the results I am getting are incorrect. The DEM generated from 2 scenes each are for April 2017 and April 2022.

April 2017 - elevation range from 9245m to 13557m.
April 2022 - elevation range from -1390m to 3316m.

This is for an approx. 2100ha watershed that's my ROI. The SRTM elevation range for the same region is 359-2571m.  I also have it verified using local geodetic points. What I am doing wrong to get such weird results?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: No GIS software - SNAP/SNAPHU to create the interferograms and unwrap the SAR data.

Comment: That is the Sentinel 1 Toolbox on SNAP. I have never created DSMs from SAR so looking for a bit of understanding too on why following the official protocol prescribed by ESA is not working. Perhaps a wrong choice of tiles?